# Reading images from AXIS ip camera using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, ip-camera

I am trying to access AXIS IP camera from my program using OpenCV.
My OpenCV version is 3.1. I follow this tutorial [link](http://funvision.blogspot.sg/2015/11/opencv-300-videocapture-file-web-camera.html).

I have all libraries installed.
My following program can load mp4 video successfully. That means ffmpeg and necessary libraries are working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture vcap("test.mp4");
    cv::Mat image;
//    const string address = "rtsp://root:pass@192.168.0.90/axis-media/media.amp?camera=1";
//    if(!vcap.open(address)){
//      std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file " << std::endl;
//      return -1;
//    }
    for(;;){
        if(!vcap.read(image)){
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey(0);
        }
        cv::imshow("Display", image);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to access the IP Camera as follow

```
cv::VideoCapture vcap("rtsp://root:pass@192.168.0.90/axis-media/media.amp?camera=1");
```

I have the following error

```
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Could 
not open resource for reading and writing.
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /home/Softwares/opencv/opencv/modules
/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 818
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/Softwares/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.
cpp:818: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
 in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer
```

User is root and password is pass and ip 192.168.0.90 are all defaults.

My if config gave me

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:2a:72:c6:b8:13  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba2a:72ff:fec6:b813/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:723959 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:116637 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:199422245 (199.4 MB)  TX bytes:13701699 (13.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:24829 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24829 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2502903 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:2502903 (2.5 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:a8:cd:99:92:60  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

What could be the problem for this access to the camera?

Thanks

Comment: Have you used `gst-launch` to see the camera view? That should work first.

Comment: The problem is at network configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at network configuration.
I need to set static ip address as follow.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

Then reboot the pc.

After that I am fine to use

```
cv::VideoCapture vcap("rtsp://root:pass@192.168.0.90/axis-media/media.amp?camera=1");
```